# Running Counts based on two dates

Tags: r

I have two fields of dates, act_dt will always have a date and cl_dt will NOT always have a date.  I need to calculate how much pending work there is based on these two fields.  I have tried a couple of methods, but I am not versed in many of the window functions or rolling functions that might make this task easier.

The field cl_dt represents the date the work was closed.  So to calculate pending the cl_dt must be greater than the act_dt or NA.  Once cl_dt == act_dt then the row should no longer count in pending.

```
act_dt <- c("2018-10-01", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04")
cl_dt <- c("2018-10-04", NA, "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04")
method_test <- data.frame(cbind(act_dt, cl_dt))
method_test$act_dt <- as.Date(method_test$act_dt)
method_test$cl_dt <- as.Date(method_test$cl_dt)

# Expected Output
      act_dt      cl_dt pending
1 2018-10-01 2018-10-04       1
2 2018-10-02       <NA>       2
3 2018-10-03 2018-10-03       2
4 2018-10-04 2018-10-04       1
```

I've attempted needlessly complex ifelse statements piped inside of dplyr, without any success.

Comment: What are the rules to compute `pending`?

Comment: I've added to the post to explain how it would be calculated.

Comment: *"Once `cl_dt==act_dt` then the row should no longer count in pending"*, but you have two instances of `cl_dt==act_dt` with different values of `pending`.

Comment: Right it should add through the cl_dt, or for the remainder of the data if cl_dt == NA.  It is like a conditional cumulative sum.

Comment: If `pending` is a cumulative value, then why does it decrement on `2018-10-04`? Are you just looking for `with(method_test, cumsum(is.na(cl_dt) | (act_dt < cl_dt)))`?

Comment: I will have to test that when I have my computer.  It decrements because the very first 'pending' item was conpleted on 10/4.  The only remaining pending item is from the NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can unfortunately not easily be vectorized, since you effectively need to consider a row as complete only when the `cl_dt` has passed. Here's a solution that explodes into an `n`-by-`n` matrix (`n` is the number of rows), so I hope you're not doing this on twenty years of daily data ...

```
m <- with(method_test, outer(act_dt, cl_dt, function(a,b) is.na(b) | a<b))
rowSums(m & lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE))
# [1] 1 2 2 1
```

This "explodes" because it is comparing

```
"2018-10-01" with c("2018-10-04", NA, "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04")
"2018-10-02" with c("2018-10-04", NA, "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04")
"2018-10-03" with c("2018-10-04", NA, "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04")
"2018-10-04" with c("2018-10-04", NA, "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04")
```

thereby producing the square matrix:

```
m
#       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Since we aren't interested in looking *backwards*, we reduce this with the lower-triangle (and diagonal):

```
m & lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

What this is saying, looking at the *columns*:

- first column (T, T, T, F) is in still "in-effect" until the fourth row; since that is `"2018-10-04"`, it is considered closed and no longer pending;
- second column (F, T, T, T) is not in effect on line one (since it hasn't started yet ... ergo the `lower.tri`), but because its `cl_dt` is `NA`, it will remain `TRUE`;
- third and fourth columns are all-false, because they opens/closes on the same day

Another attempt that doesn't explode the matrix would involve iterating row-by-row, looking for the right intervals:

```
colSums(with(method_test, sapply(act_dt, function(x) {
  x >= act_dt & (is.na(cl_dt) | x < cl_dt)
})))
# [1] 1 2 2 1
```

The first is a bit faster than the second, but only with this small data ... larger data *might* have a different relative performance:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  a = {
    m <- with(method_test, outer(act_dt, cl_dt, function(a,b) is.na(b) | a<b))
    rowSums(m & lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE))
  },
  b = {
    colSums(with(method_test, sapply(act_dt, function(x) {
      x >= act_dt & (is.na(cl_dt) | x < cl_dt)
    })))
  }
)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr min  lq mean median  uq max neval
#     a  55  58   64     61  65 126   100
#     b 174 178  187    180 184 379   100
```

---

**Edit**

If the data has an additional column for grouping, then this code can be put in a `do(...)` block:

```
library(dplyr)
# sample data, slightly-different
method_test2 <- bind_rows(mutate(method_test, id=1L), mutate(method_test, id=2L)[c(1,2,4),])
method_test2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({
    dat <- .
    m <- with(dat, outer(act_dt, cl_dt, function(a,b) is.na(b) | a<b))
    dat$pending <- rowSums(m & lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE))
    dat
  })
```

Comment: This worked very well for me.  Can you think of a way this could be implemented within the dplyr piping that would account for a grouped tibble?

Comment: If you're talking about replacing this method with `dplyr`, I can't think of a way to group it such that this becomes easy ... perhaps somebody can find a way I'm not thinking of. If you're walking about grouping on another variable that is not in this example, then you can put this code in a `do(...)` block, replacing `method_test` with `.`, and assigning to a column ... and all should work per-group as you'd expect. (See my edit.)